# AngularJS: Transfer current state from view to controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `UI-Router`. I have a view where I need to catch it's current state and send it to a controller as parameter to a `ng-click` function in a button.

The following approach returned `undefined` when I `console.log` the transferred object inside the function `transferState`

```
<button ng-click="transferState($state.current.name)">Click me</button>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you use ui router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common way, would be to inject two heavily used services into `$rootScope`. This is used in the sample app - [app.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/app.js)

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {

  // It's very handy to add references to $state and $stateParams to the $rootScope
  // so that you can access them from any scope within your applications.For example,
  // <li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('contacts.list') }"> will set the <li>
  // to active whenever 'contacts.list' or one of its decendents is active.

    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

Now, each view can access these directly. The sample application is [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/).

Comment: Actually, it works only when I declare my "transferState()" function inside my controller as "$rootScope.transferState()" !!

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass $state to your controller or in run-phase to $rootscope.
Then you can access $state from inside your views.

e.g.:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.$state = $state;

});
```

see also the docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#note-about-using-state-within-a-template

Comment: The problem is when I pass the current state within a ng-click function I get undefined inside my controller!

Comment: Actually, it works only when I declare my "transferState()" function inside my controller as "$rootScope.transferState()" !!

Comment: @ng-user is myCtrl instanced by ui-router via $stateProvider? Or is this your default/main controller. Typically you have multiple controller bound to ui-router states which getting active when the state becomes active, and then you have a scope on that controller which binds to the view where you have the click handler. If you declare transferState on the rootScope then the view will have access to it via angulars lookup mechanism.